# What compiler and options do I need to compile Raspberry Pi RP2040 code on Godbolt?

Tags: cortex-m, raspberry-pi-pico, compiler-options, rp2040, godbolt

I would like to explore code optimisation on the Raspberry Pi [Pico's](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/raspberry-pi-pico.html) microcontroller, [RP2040](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/rp2040.html), using [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/), but I'm not sure which compiler options to use. The microcontroller is an Arm Cortex-M0. I'd be happy if I could at least set it to compile for a generic Arm Cortex-M0 platform.

Which compiler should I choose, and which options?

Comment: So you already know how to select ARM GCC in Compiler Explorer and add the `-mcpu=cortex-m0` option, right?  Are you looking for anything else?  What criteria will you use to judge potential answers that people might take the time to write up?

Comment: I just found out you have to add another option as well: `-mcpu=cortex-m0 -mfloat-abi=soft`